# MOBAC cannot generate the required file name for osmdroid

Tags: android, openstreetmap

Now I am trying to load my zip files with using osmdroid lib from the sd card. My zip file is osmdroid zip format is generated by the MOBAC. The file path in my zip is not the same with the generated file path from the osmdroid lib.

MOBAC generated like this osmdroid\Mapnik\13\6282\3706.png

osmdroid lib required like this osmdroid\Mapnik\13\4060\4060.png

How can I fix this? And is there any way to customize both of them? I spend a lot of time for that. Could you please give me some advice.

Thanks!

Comment: the file path is not ur problem , u r refering another tile , thats it

Comment: Now I am using MOBAC 1.9.3 and osmdroid 3.0.7. Is there problem in those versions?

Comment: u shold give the path of osmdroid.zip folder and not individual tile

Comment: Yes I give the path of osmdroid zip folder which is generated by the MOBAC. The osmdroid-android lib only found the zip file. But it cannot load tiles from zip because the osmdrid-android lib generate different file name to load the tiles from this zip.

Answer (score 0):

The osm tile names are pseudo standard:
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames
If you give coordinates of the required location, we can calculate the correct names and we can tell which one is wrong.

If mobac is wrong, one reason could be that you didn't change the output format in the "atlas/convert atlas format" menu to osmdroid.